# Why is my read-only Postgresql user being denied read permissions on tables?

Tags: postgresql

I am aware that similar questions have been asked before, but the answers do not appear to solve my problem, so I think a more complete answer would be valuable.

I would like to create a read-only user for a postgresql database. I have already granted access to the server for my user using the pg_hba.conf file.

As the postgres admin user, I have run the following commands:

```
CREATE ROLE read_only_user NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE the_database TO read_only_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public to read_only_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_only_user;
ALTER ROLE read_only_user WITH PASSWORD '*********************';
ALTER ROLE read_only_user VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
ALTER ROLE read_only_user WITH LOGIN;
ALTER USER read_only_user SET search_path = public;
```

As a result, I am able to log in to the the_database DB locally, and remotely using a DB client, with username and password authentication and I can list the tables in the database. However, any attempt to select or view the contents of the database results in

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation the_table
```

What other permissions are needed, since as far as I can tell, all the necessary permissions are granted.

Comment: What is the *exact* name of `the_table`, and in what schema is it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - the_table is called "the_table" and is in the "public" schema of the "the_database" database. So the structure is the_database > public > the_table. I could give you the real names, but they would be similarly arbitrary since they're unique to my application.

Comment: Are you sure it is a table, not a VIEW?

Comment: The reason I asked for the real names is that this problem is probably caused by a typo or similar, not by a misbehavior of the database system. In the same vein, can you show the exact statement that caused the error? Is the behavior different if you do the same as user `postgres`?

Comment: Your script works here, so it must either be a typo, or `... remotely using a DB client` uses a different database, schema, search_path, or user id. Maybe the postgres logfiles can tell you more.